# Error in selecting nullable using linq to Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I am using linq to Entities. I am trying to select a `nullable Int` field with below code but I am getting `Exception`

```
    List<MyClass> myList = myContext.Accounts
            .Where(x => x.ACCOUNT_TYPE_ID == 58 && x.IS_DELETED == 0)
            .Select(x=> new PayorCode
                {
                    Id = x.ID,
                    Payor = x.CODE_NUM + " - "+ x.DESCRIPTION
                }).ToList();
```

In `Accounts` property `CODE_NUM` is of `Nullable<global::System.Int32>` .

 I am getting the below exception

> Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

How should I use the nullable field in `Linq to Entites` ? I tried with `Convert.ToInt32` and `object.Equals` but both didn't worked. 

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You say you are using `LinqToSql` but the error message says `LINQ to Entities` which is entity framework, which is totally different.  Which is it?

Comment: Also where `CODE_NUM` is null, what should happen to that concatenated string?

Comment: @BenRobinson .. sorry .. you are correct it's Linq to Entities as I am using Entity framework

Answer (score 3):

Dealing with nullable ints in EF should be no different to dealing with them under normal circumstances. You can check that they have a value using `.HasValue`, you can read the value directly using `.Value` and you can null-coalesce using `??`. Depending on what you want to happen in the case that this property is null, you should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
.Select(x=> new PayorCode
            {
                Id = x.ID,
                Payor = x.CODE_NUM.HasValue 
                            ? x.CODE_NUM.Value + " - "+ x.DESCRIPTION
                            : "CODE_NUM Missing"
            })
```

or perhaps:

```
.Select(x=> new PayorCode
            {
                Id = x.ID,
                Payor = (x.CODE_NUM ?? "0") + " - "+ x.DESCRIPTION,
            })
```

Comment: By this way , I am getting -  Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: Are you sure your model/edmx is set up right. This is starting to seem like a problem in your model, rather than any problem with code. I have used nullable types hundreds of times in EF without issue with code very similar to the above.

Comment: Other than this issue .. everything working fine .. so assuming that model is set up properly.. Well..How can I check if there is some problem in model/edmx?

Answer (score -1):

The class list "List" can't be used with the strongly type class list PayorCode referenced in your select. Either use a "var query = ..." along with PayorCode or if List is the same as PayorCode then substitute PayorCode with MyClass. So 
.Select(x => new MyClass { ....}

Then answer 2 should work fine.